# Is there a command-line application for converting a one-frame Flash movie to SVG?

Tags: flash, command-line, swf, svg

Is there a command-line application for conversion of a one-frame Flash movie to SVG?
[This project](http://swf2svg.sourceforge.net/) doesn't contain any files.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about Flash programming, and trying to find utilities that do this mostly turned up online services, but nothing that could be used locally. However, I hope [this piece of code](http://wonderfl.net/c/sPjI) (that I found from a [question at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542614/how-to-convert-a-swf-displayobject-to-svg-data)) can help.